# how to get both values of ORDER and OrderItems

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase Cloud Firestore and load it into my ReactJS app upon loading into the browser.

In this code, I only get the value of `ORDER`.

How to get both the values `ORDER` and `OrderItems`?

```
componentDidMount() {
  firestore
    .collection('ORDERS')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const ORDERS = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        ORDERS.push(data);
      });
      this.setState({ ORDERS: ORDERS });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

[image]

[how to get both the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZotyB.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to fetch one order and then all of the orderItems that go with it?  Your current query fetches all orders.

Comment: my current query fetches only ORDERS like deliveryPrice ,OrderStatus etc but i want to fetch both Order and OrderItems

Comment: It is usual to list the ORDERS, then when a user selects an order, you fetch the orderItems for that order.  If you want your page to fetch all of the orders and all of the orderItems, you may have some scaling issues.  If this really is what you want, I can show you how to achieve that, but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: I want to show both details bro because many details of user is in the OrderItems like address and orderid so I have to fetch it anyhow, please show me how to achieve that ,if anything which gives the key will be very helpful to me @JasonBerryman

Comment: Hey please reply @Jason Berryman

Comment: Hey. Sorry. I've been offline this weekend.  Give me a few minutes and I'll show you how to retrieve documents from a sub-collection.  Please note, it is usual to list the orders and then when a user selects an order, it fetches the orderItems.  Fetching **all** orderItems for **all** orders may prove slow and costly

Comment: orderId is not defined @Jason Berryman

Comment: When a user selects an order document, you will get an ID.  If you want to iterate through all of the ORDER documents, you can get the ref or the ID of each document in your `forEach` method.  I'd recommend that you watch the "Get to know Cloud Firestore" series on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ

Answer (score 0):

### Fetching items from a sub-collection

You are currently fetching the items from the `ORDERS` collection.  You can take an order document and fetch the `orderItems` within it by using a reference.

I've used **async/await**. However, you can easily convert this to use promises.

```
// Set the reference for the order document
const orderRef = firestore.collection('ORDERS').doc(orderId);

// Fetch the document and extract the data
const orderDS = await orderRef.get();
const orderData = orderDS.data();

// Fetch the orderItems and add them to an array
const orderItemsQS = await orderRef.collection('orderItems').get();
const orderItems = orderItemsQS.docs.map(orderItemQDS => (
  const {id, ref, path} = orderItemsQDS; // You can add one or more of these to make it easy to update values back into Firestore
  const data = orderItemsQDS.data();
  return {id, ref, path, data};
));
```

You can either fetch these as you use your `forEach` and `push` or (recommended) only fetch `orderItems` when a user has selected an `ORDER`.

### Alternative document references

#### Option 1

```
const orderRef = firestore.collection('ORDERS').doc(orderId);
const orderItemsQS = await orderRef.collection('orderItems).get();
```

#### Option 2

```
const orderItemsQS = await firestore
  .collection('ORDERS').doc(orderId)
  .collection('orderItems').get();
```

#### Option 3

```
const orderItemsQS = await firestore.collection(`ORDERS/${orderId}/orderItems`).get();
```

### Naming conventions

I add the following suffixes to my variable names to make them easier to read:

- QS  = QuerySnapshot
- QDS = QueryDocumentSnapshot
- DS  = DocumentSnapshot

### Javascript reference

This is a really useful resource to help you when getting started.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore